# How to serialize a NSPredicate object?

Tags: core-data, ios, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Is there a way to inspect a NSPredicate object for the purposes of serializing it into a URL? I am trying to retrieve the data remotely and need to translate the predicate object into a URL with querystring parameters that the server understands.

This was inspired by a talk given in WWDC 2010 called "Building a Server Driven User EXperience" where the speakers talk about using Core-Data and with a server backend. I have followed the session video and slides, but am stuck on the serializing point. For example, there is a `Person` object, and I'm trying to fetch all people whose first name is "John". I am using a subclass of `NSManagedObjectContext` called `RemoteManagedObjectContext`, which overrides the `executeFetchRequest` method, and is supposed to send the call to the server instead. The fetch request is being created as (ellipsed non-essential parts):

```
@implementation PeopleViewController

- (NSArray *)getPeople {
    RemoteFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[RemoteFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = ...
    NSPredicate *template = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                @"name == $NAME AND endpoint = $ENDPOINT"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [template predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:...];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    // the custom subclass of NSManagedObjectContext executes this
    return [remoteMOC executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
}

@end
```

Now inside the custom subclass of `NSManagedObjectContext`, how can I serialize the fetch request into querystring parameters suitable for the server. So given the above fetch request, the corresponding URL would be:

```
http://example.com/people?name=John
```

It is possible to get a string representation of the predicate which returns,

```
name == "John" AND endpoint == "people"
```

that I can parse to get the parameters `name`, and `endpoint`. However, is it possible to do it without parsing the string? Here's a partial implementation of the `RemoteManagedObjectContext` class.

```
@implementation RemoteManagedObjectContext

- (NSArray *)executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error {
    // this gives name == "John" AND endpoint == "people"
    // don't know how else to retrieve the predicate data
    NSLog(@"%@", [[request predicate] predicateFormat]);

    ...
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even better than a string representation is an object-oriented representation!  And it's done automatically!

First, check the class of the `NSPredicate`.  It will be an `NSCompoundPredicate`.  Cast it to an appropriate variable.

You'll then see that it's `compoundPredicateType` is `NSAndPredicateType`, just like you'd expect.

You can also see that the array returned by `-subpredicates` reveals 2 `NSComparisonPredicates`.

The first subpredicate has a left expression of type `NSKeyPathExpressionType` and a `-keyPath` of `@"name"`, the operator is `NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType`.  The right expression will be an `NSExpression` of type `NSConstantValueExpressionType`, and the `-constantValue` will be `@"John"`.

The second subpredicate will be similar, except that the left expression's `keyPath` will be `@"endpoint"`, and the right expression's `constantValue` will be `@"people"`.

If you want more in-depth information on turning `NSPredicates` into an HTTP Get request, check out my [StackOverflow framework, "StackKit"](https://github.com/davedelong/StackKit), which does just that.  It's basically a framework that behaves similarly to CoreData, but uses StackOverflow.com (or any other stack exchange site) to retrieve information.  Underneath, it's doing a *lot* to convert `NSPredicate` objects into a URL.  You're also welcome to email me any specific questions you have.